# Prove bounded linear operator equal 0

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded linear operators on a Hilbert Space $H$. Show if $A^*A+B^*B=0$ then $A=B=0$.

So far I have shown that $A^*A+B^*B$ is self-adjoint.

This means that $A^*A+B^*B = \overline{(A^*A)^T}+\overline{(B^*B)^T}$.

It is also obvious that $A^*A = -B^*B$ which gives that $||A|| = ||B||$ with some proof.

I'm fairly certain this should be an easy proof to show, but I am stuck and not sure the next steps to take.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $x \in H$. Then:
$$\langle A^*A x,x \rangle=\langle A x, A x \rangle=\|Ax \|² \geq 0$$
using for example $A^*A=-B^* B$ you can deduce that $\forall x \in H$:
$$ 0 \leq \|Ax\|^2 = -\|Bx\|^2 \leq 0$$
which gives the result.

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was going to have to use the inner product, but we have focused more on the theory of operators and not very much into their application.  I understand now